# Relation between harmonic vector field and harmonic 1-form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-analysis, differential-operators

> **Definition 1:** A unit vector field $X$ side to be **harmonic** if it is critical point for the following energy function
>   $$E(X)=\frac{1}{2}\int_M\|dX\|^2dvol_g=\frac{m}{2}vol(M,g)+\int_M\|\nabla X\|^2dvol_g.$$
>
> **Definition 2:** A 1-form $\omega$ side to be **harmonic** if it is in kernel of Laplace operator. i.e. $\Delta\omega=(d\delta+\delta d)\omega=0$.

**Question:** Is there relation between two above definitions? Please give a simple example.

**Update:** I find some theorem in this topic:

> > **Theorem 1.** If $\omega$ is harmonic and $X$ is the dual vector field, we have that $\mathrm{div}X = 0$.
> >
> > **Theorem 2.** If $X$ is a vector field on $(M,g)$ and $\omega(v) = g(X,v)$ is the dual 1-form, then
> >     $$\mathrm{div}X = −\delta\omega.$$

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you could provide more context. What is "the energy function" here?

Comment: Ok. the question is updated.

Comment: The duality from the metric between 1-forms and vector fields shows that your energy is the usual one on 1-forms for which the critical 1-forms are the harmonic ones (see any reference on Hodge theory). But the restriction to unit vector fields is a bit unusual, and doesn't give the same Euler-Lagrange equations, I imagine.

Comment: @BenMcKay: maybe not exactly a reference on Hodge theory; the OP may be slightly confused by [Weitzenbock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitzenb%C3%B6ck_identity) if we bring the form Laplacian into the picture.

Comment: Thanks Ben McKay. But in every reference i can't find this relation.

Comment: Note that $0 = \Delta_g(1) = \Delta_g (g(X,X)) = 2 g(X,\Delta_g X) + 2 g(\nabla X, \nabla X)$ you actually have that a unit harmonic vector field on a Riemannian manifold must be parallel. It seems *very strange* to require that $X$ is unit in the definition.

Comment: @Willie Wong thanks for your Hint. what is your means of harmonic? Def. 1 or Def. 2?

Comment: Harmonic forms are almost never unit length, as far as I am aware.  It would appear to me that Definition 1 is a very special definition, largely unrelated to Definition 2.  You can of course talk about harmonic vector fields (i.e. dual to harmonic forms) but this results in a different object than your "harmonic unit vector fields".

Comment: Perhaps you don't mean to have the word "unit" in your definition of a harmonic vector field?

Comment: I meant Harmonic in the sense of in the kernel of the Laplace-Beltrami operator, which is the sense given by _both_ of your definitions.

Comment: I think that the OP is mixing up a couple of different things: The definition of harmonic for a 1-form is standard, but for *unit* vector fields, there is another notion of 'harmonic':  Regard $S(M)$, the unit sphere bundle of $(M,g)$, as a Riemannian manifold in the natural way and then ask whether a unit vector field $X:M\to S(M)$ is harmonic as a mapping between two Riemannian manifolds.  There is actually an additional subtlety, in that one can ask that $X$ be a critical point of the energy functional *when one only varies $X$ through sections of $S(M)\to M$* (instead of through all maps).

Comment: Many thanks R. Bryant. I still did not get the answer my question. is this true: if $X:M\to S(M)$ is Harmonic in the sense of a mapping between two Riemannian manifolds if and only if $\omega= X^\flat$ is Harmonic as 1-form.?

Comment: @C.F.G:  Oh. The answer to that is 'no'.  For example, if one takes a left-invariant unit vector field $X$ on $M^3=\mathrm{SU}(2)\simeq S^3$ endowed with its bi-invariant metric as a Lie group, then $X:M\to S(M)$ is harmonic as a map between Riemannian manifolds (and as a section of $S(M)$ as well), but $X^\flat$ is not a harmonic $1$-form on $M$, since the only harmonic $1$-form on $M$ is the one that vanishes identically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two notions are related, but they are not the same.

The condition for a *unit* vector field $X$ on a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ to be harmonic is *not* the same as the condition that the dual $1$-form $X^\flat$ be harmonic.  The point is that, for unit vector fields, one defines the energy as the energy of the map $X:M\to S(M)$ where $S(M)$ is the unit sphere bundle of $(M,g)$ endowed with the Sasaki metric and one says that a unit vector field is harmonic if it is a critical point of this energy.  This is not the same as the energy of the $1$-form $X^\flat$ in general (though it can be sometimes, for example, if the metric is flat).

A simple example is to take $(M,g)$ to be $S^3=\mathrm{SU}(2)$ endowed with its natural bi-invariant metric.  Then any unit left-invariant (or right-invariant) tangent vector field $X$ is harmonic in the above sense, but the dual $1$-form $\omega = X^\flat$ is not harmonic as a $1$-form because the only harmonic $1$-form on $S^3$ is the zero $1$-form. (Since $H^1(S^3) = 0$, this follows, for instance, from the Hodge Theorem.)

There are several good sources for study of this notion of harmonicity of unit vector fields.  There is a whole book, *Harmonic Vector Fields: Variational Principles and Differential Geometry*, by S. Dragomir and Domenico Perrone  (Elsevier, 2012), but there are also articles that you may find useful:  For example, see the survey article *Volume, energy and generalized energy of unit vector fields on Berger spheres. Stability of Hopf vector fields* by Olga Gil-Medrano and Ana Hurtado (http://www.ugr.es/~ahurtado/PDF/correcciones.pdf) and the references therein.