# Why trace is more natural than (preferred to) determinant for smooth map $f:M\to N$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, traces, pullback

[Cross-post from MSE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3880939/272127)

For a continuous map $f:(M,g)\to (N,h)$, between Riemannian manifolds $(M,g)$ and $(N,h)$ we can pullback $h$ by $f$. Most experts take the trace from this new tensor and work with it, i.e. $\operatorname{tr}_g(f^*h)$ which I think is equal to $\lvert df\rvert^2$. I think there is a simple reason from *Linear Algebra* that perhaps I missed it that

> **Question:** why they use trace (e.g. [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1702651/272127), [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/237965/90655) and [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/273908/90655) posts) and not determinant or any other operator?

One primary reason is that it is similar to $\operatorname{tr} A^tB$ that is an inner product over $n\times n$ matrices.

In the case of energy density of harmonic maps, $e(f)\mathrel{:=}\frac{1}{2}\lvert df\rvert^2$ is very natural operator because it is similar to (up to a constant $m$) the [kinetic energy formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ in physics.

But these are not sufficient to not consider the determinant (or any other operator) case. I want to know: Is the following expression meaningful and can it reveal nice properties of the space as well as trace case? or that is same as trace case?
$$K(f)\mathrel{:=}\int_M\det_g(f^*h)d\mathrm{vol}_g.$$

It is also helpful remember that the trace is $\sum_i\lambda_i$ and determinant is $\prod_i\lambda_i$.

Comment: A related question I have had for a while that might help (or not): In algebraic geometry and number theory, it is very easy to use the trace and determinant of a linear map (often as the trace and norm of an element in some ring) and I always wondered why other symmetric polynomials in the eigenvalues didn't get considered. The answer is usually that we can somehow exploit the linearity or multiplicativity in some fashion and the other symmetric polynomials in the eigenvalues don't have such nice functionality. In your case, maybe being additive is a really nice property for the trace ?

Comment: I am sure some experts consider $A(f)=\int_M\sqrt{\det_g(f^*h)}dvol_g.$

Comment: @Sebastian: Any reference?

Comment: In the elliptic case, general functionals of the form $\int L(I_1, I_2, I_3)$ is considered in elasticity. Here the dimensions of $M, N$ are both 3, and $I_1 = \mathrm{tr} f^*h$, $I_3 = \det f^*h$, and $I_2$ is the quadratic invariant.

Comment: In the case where $(M,g)$ is Lorentzian, I treated some general properties of the Euler Lagrange equation in https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/28/21/215008 ; the case that Sebastian mentioned is a special case of the Born-Infeld model, and is related to minimal surfaces.

Comment: @C.F.G.: the integrand is independent of the metric $g$ on $M$, and using $g=f^*h$ the integral is the area (or volume) of $f(M)\subset N$. The critical points of this functional are minimal surfaces, which are well-studied objects in differential geometrie for centuries.

Comment: @WillieWong: Thanks for reference. Is the special case of $L(I_1, I_2, I_3)$ known in  elasticity? Like the kinetic energy in physics?

Comment: In the case of elastodynamics, see http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=AIHPA_1998__69_3_275_0 There are probably also references you can find for the static case.

Comment: See @D.Savitt's wonderful [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/2815) to the analogous question in representation theory.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to understand  the special case of a linear map $T:U\to V$ where $U,V$ are Euclidean vector spaces. (Think $U=T_pM$, $V=T_{f(p)}N$, $T=df(p)$.)

Suppose first that $n=\dim V\leq \dim U=m$.
Let $\lambda_1,\dotsc, \lambda_n, $ be the eigenvalues of the symmetric nonnegative operators $TT^*:V\to V$, multiplicities included. Then (see Lemma 1.1 in [The co-area formula](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Coarea.pdf)) there exist Euclidean coordinates $x^1,\dotsc, x^{m}$ on $U$ and Euclidean coordinates  $y^1, \dotsc, y^n$ on $V$ such that $T$ is described un these coordinates  by
$$
y^i=\sqrt{\lambda_i} x^i,\;\;\forall i=1,\dotsc, n.
$$
Denote by $g_V$ the inner product on $V$ and by $g_U$ the inner product.  Then
$$
g_V=\sum_{i=1}^n (dy^i)^2,\;\;T^* g_V= \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i (dx^i)^2.
$$
We deduce $\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}$
\begin{align*}
\tr_{g_U} T^*g_V&{}=\sum_i \lambda_i=\tr TT^*, \\
\det\limits_{g_U} T^*g_V&{}=0. 
\end{align*}
In this case, more useful in applications is the  *Jacobian* of $T$, $\DeclareMathOperator{\Jac}{Jac}$
$$
\Jac(T)\mathrel{:=}\prod_{i=1}^n\lambda_i =\det T T^*.
$$
The Jacobian  of $T$ plays an important role in the *coarea formula*,
$$
\int_M \Jac_x(f) u(x) dV_g(x)=\int_N\left(\int_{f^{-1}(y)} u(x) dV_{f^{-1}(y)}(x)\right) dV_h(y),\;\;\forall u\in C_0(M). 
$$
This contains the change-in-variables formula as a special case.

If $m=\dim  U<\dim V$, then  we can find  Euclidean  coordinates $x^1,\dotsc, x^m$ and Euclidean coordinates $y^1,\dotsc, y^n$ on $V$ such that, in these coordinates $T$ is described by
$$ y^i=\sqrt{\mu_i}x^i,\;\;\forall i=1,\dotsc, m,\;\;y_j=0,\;\;j>m,
 $$
where $\mu_1,\dotsc, \mu_m$ are the eigenvalues of the symmetric nonnegative operator $T^*T:U\to U$. (To see this apply the previous result to the map $T^*:V\to U$.)

In this case
\begin{align*}
\tr_{g_U} T^*g_V&{}=\sum_{i=1}^m \mu_i=\tr T^*T, \\
\det\nolimits_{g_U} T^*g_V&{}= \prod_{i=1}^m \mu_i=\det T^*T.
\end{align*}